# Add framework in iOS application from outside of xcode

Tags: ios

I have add some framework like  Google,Facebook in my  iOS project and when i compress the project code file and take the code any other system then show that framework is not available so can you tell me how can i add framework in iOS application?

Comment: Are the actual file of those framework also being copied with the project? Because when you add a framework, its likely added as a symbolic link to that framework and doesn't copy files to your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Click on Project[image]

2) Go to Bulid Phases , Link Binary With Libraries , click on ADD button [image]

3)Click on Add Other Button , Go your library path and Add to project [image]

Comment: where i can get facebook framework for ios i get only facebook-ios-sdk-3.19.pkg from facebook developer site, so please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an older version, the best way is to use cocapods and then specify in your Podfile the following line:
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.18.0' 
In that example you would receive the sdk version 3.18